# Binary values not converting to string values

Tags: python, string, binary, compression

I am using these first theree functions with the function (decode) that I believe I am having an issue with

```
def binary_to_char(s):
    main = s[0]
    # for short binval
    if main == "0":
# s = 2, so get the first two values
       WantedVal = s[0:2]
       s = s[2:]

# This next half is for long values
    else:
      #  H = 4, so this gets the first 4 values within the string
        WantedVal = s[0:4]
        s = s[4:]

    return WantedVal, s
```

## function gets the inputted BinVal and returns corresponded character

```
def give_char(s):
    try:
        i = b.index(s)
        charVal = c[i]
    except:
        charVal = ''

    return charVal
```

## function that outputs file with binary values

```
def read_in(fn):
    f = open(fn,"r")
    s = f.read()
    f.close()

    binstr = ''
    while (s != ''):
        binval, s = retrieve_bin(s)
        binstr = binstr + binval

    # print(binstr)
    numbits = len(binstr)
    binstr = str(numbits) + '.' + binstr

    f = open("BinOutput.txt", 'w+')
    f.write(binstr)
    f.close()
```

```
print(binstr)
```

## This function takes in a text file with BinVals and creates a new file labeled

## "TextOutput.txt" which contains the characters for the file

```
def decode(fn = "BinOutput.txt"):
    f = open(fn, "r", encoding= 'utf-8')
    s = f.read()
    f.close()

 
    i = s.index('.')
    s = s[i+1:]
  
    charstr = ''
    while (s != ''):
        binval, s = binary_to_char(s)
        charstr = charstr + give_char(binval)
    f = open("TextOutput.txt", 'w+')
    f.write(charstr)`your text`
    f.close()
```

when I run decode and check the file location on my computer, I get a "TextOutput.txt" file but it is blank. How would I fix this? I am using pycharm.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? Please provide very minimal example that shows the problem. Describe what you want to achieve with your code.
As for the code itself - first thing that looks strange to me is in binary_to_char function: you read something that is supposed to be binary, but compare it with string (main == "0")